# Enforcing a template structure in git commit message

Tags: bash, git, github, git-bash

I have template that has a sample (example : WORKID # ADC0000)

> - <Git_base>/.gitmessage

I have added this to my prepare-commit-msg message in .git/hooks.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the default commit message from a file
commit_msg_file="/d/gitTest/.gitmessage"
commit_msg=$(cat "$commit_msg_file")

# Prepend the default commit message to the commit message file
echo -e "$commit_msg\n$(cat "$1")" > "$1"
```

How can I enforce it when others commit the code. I have seen https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy but unable to figure out how to connect the template and server-side hook (I am assuming client-side will not enforce it neither will be able to get it on cloning the repo, unless they set the hookPath which can again not be enforced).

Comment: You don't get to usurp admin authority in other people's repositories, no.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force people to use a template or a set of hooks in their own repository, and in many cases, you wouldn't want to.  For example, someone may want to create a quick WIP commit, or create squash or fixup commits to rebase into their branch later, or any number of other advanced development techniques, and you wouldn't want to prevent that.

What you can do is use a shell (or Python or Ruby) script in the hook to verify that the message meets some sort of formatting standards.  If you're including something like an ticket ID, then the best place to do that is in the trailers, which are specifically designed for that purpose.

How to wire this up depends on what you're doing.  The easiest way is in your CI system, which you can do with something like this (assuming you're using the `Ticket-ID` trailer):

```
git log -1 --format=%B HEAD | git interpret-trailers --parse | grep -qs Ticket-ID
```

That will exit 0 if it finds the ticket ID, and nonzero if it doesn't, which typically will cause your branch to fail.  (Note that it doesn't look through all the commits, just the latest.)  You can also do different things if your structure is different, something like this:

```
git rev-list --format=%B HEAD | ruby -e '
def verify(text, commit)
  unless text.nil? || text =~ /^Ticket-ID: (\d+)/
    $stderr.puts "#{commit} is malformed"
    exit 1
  end
end
text = nil
commit = nil
while gets
  if $_ =~ /^commit ([0-9a-f]+)/
    verify(text, commit)
    commit = $1
    text = ""
  else
    text += $_
  end
end
verify(text, commit)'
```

If you're using a `pre-receive` hook instead, then you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

while read old new ref
do
    if echo $new | grep -qs '^0+'
    then
        # deletion, probably do nothing
        :
    elif echo $old | grep -qs '^0+'
    then
        # creation
        git rev-list --format=%B "$new" | my-script "$ref"
    else
        # creation
        git rev-list --format=%B "$old..$new" | my-script "$ref"
    fi
done
```

where `my-script REF` is a script that parses the output of `git rev-list` for the reference REF and exits nonzero on failure.

Comment: Sorry I am failing to understand something basic say an open source project, it would want to enforce that commits to the repo follow certain commit messages follow certain standards ie it says major or minor change, track some work ID etc (which would also finally end up being tracked in semver version changelog etc) . I want the enforcement when the push to git happens (I do not have CI set on branch, so setting enforcement in CI would be after the checkin already went to git) .

Comment: You need to use CI, then.  There can be a pre-push hook, but you [cannot force people to use them](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#restrict-with-hooks).  Unless you have a pre-receive hook or CI, there's simply no way to require people to follow the standards.

Comment: "I want the enforcement when the push to git happens"—you do that in a pre-receive, vet commits being offered in a push. What people do in their own repositories is their busness. What you'll accept in yours is your business.